# How to sort an array of objects in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to sort by distance of an array of json. I've tried using the .sort() function but I'm unable to make it work. I'm coding in typescript.

```
sortArr = [
{id: 1, distance: 2.56},
{id: 2, distance: 3.65},
{id: 3, distance: 9.25},
{id: 4, distance: 5.32},
{id: 5, distance: 2.56}
]

sortArr.distance.sort(function(a,b){return a-b;});
```

Comment: "array of json", no. that is an array of objects. json is a serialized data format and is _always_ a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost got it right:

```
sortArr = [
{id: 1, distance: 2.56},
{id: 2, distance: 3.65},
{id: 3, distance: 9.25},
{id: 4, distance: 5.32},
{id: 5, distance: 2.56}
]

sortArr.sort(function(a,b){return a.distance-b.distance;});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) on your array:

```js
const array = [
  {id: 1, distance: 2.56},
  {id: 2, distance: 3.65},
  {id: 3, distance: 9.25},
  {id: 4, distance: 5.32},
  {id: 5, distance: 2.56}
];

const sorted = array.sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance);
console.log(sorted);
```

Though, `sortArr.distance.sort(function(a, b) { return a-b; });` should at least show one error:

```
Property 'distance' does not exist on type '{ id: number; distance: number; }[]'.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sortArr.sort(function(a,b){return a['distance']-b['distance'];});
```